# Application.Run skipping on 2nd loop run

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a macro which will open up an Excel file and run a macro in the newly opened file which will then generate a PowerPoint presentation, save the presentation, close the presentation, PowerPoint and the newly opened Excel file, then start the process and complete the process again with the next Excel file to be opened.

Process works fine for the first file but for the 2nd Excel file to be opened, it appears that the `Application.Run` code skips and so the process breaks at the `Set PPPRes` because there isn't a presentation to be made active as one isn't created in the `Application.Run` process.

Any suggestions as to why it might be breaking?

```
Sub CreatePowerPoints()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook, PPApp As PowerPoint.Application, PPPRes As PowerPoint.Presentation
    
    lr = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Year1 = Right(Date, 4) - 1
    Year2 = Right(Date, 4)
    RepPer = Left(Sheet1.Range("REPPERIOD").Value, 3)
    RepTem = Sheet1.Range("REPTEMPLATE")
    
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
        
    For x = 6 To lr
        ChkPath1b = wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("P" & x) & Year1 & "\" & wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("REPMONTH")
        ChkPath2b = wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("P" & x) & Year2 & "\" & wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("REPMONTH")
        If Sheet1.Range("J" & x) = "Yes" Then
            Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
            wbName = wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("D" & x) & " - Client Engine.xlsm"
                    
            If RepPer = "Dec" Then
                Filename = ChkPath1b & "\" & wbName
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
            End If
            If RepPer <> "Dec" Then
                Filename = ChkPath2b & "\" & wbName
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
            End If
       
            Application.Run "'" & wbName & "'!SendToPPT"
        
            Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
            Set PPPRes = PPApp.ActivePresentation
        
            If RepPer = "Dec" Then
                PPPRes.SaveAs ChkPath1b & "\" & wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("D" & x) & " - Monthly Report.pptm"
            Else
                PPPRes.SaveAs ChkPath2b & "\" & wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("D" & x) & " - Monthly Report.pptm"
            End If
        
            'wbName = Nothing
        
            wb.Close False
            PPPRes.Close
            PPApp.Quit
        
            wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("H" & x).Value = "REPORT CREATED"
            wb1.Sheets("Tracking").Range("j" & x).Value = "No"
        End If
    Next x
    MsgBox "All PowerPoints created."
End Sub
```

Comment: You are assuming that `Application.Run "'" & wbName & "'!SendToPPT"` will create a presentation as you correctly identified. I feel your code can be made shorter and robust so that the code doesnt fail. Can you share what `SendToPPT` does?

Comment: I can't share the code for 'SendToPPT'.  At a high level, it opens up a PowerPoint template, copys charts and slides in other files into this template to generate the presentation.  The macro is standard across all of the Excel files being opened, so its generation on the first file but skipping on the 2nd one is a mystery.